# Shortcut for deleting a line of SQL

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to delete your current line of SQL without highlighting the full line?  I want to delete the line that my cursor is on without selecting the whole line.

So in visual studio CTRL + L will delete the full line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

Works for me in SSMS 2014.